# How can apply truncate command on a table which is referenced in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table masterTbl and detailTbl which structure is given below...

```
--PRIMARY TABLE
CREATE TABLE masterTbl (
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY, 
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
description VARCHAR(max))

--FORIGN TABLE
CREATE TABLE detailTbl (
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
m_id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_mid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES masterTbl(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
details VARCHAR(MAX))
```

I want to perform

```
TRUNCATE TABLE masterTbl
```

but it is encountering error "Cannot truncate table 'testDB.dbo.masterTbl' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint."

How can i use **TRUNCATE** command on **masterTbl**??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove  the FK constraint `fk_mid`.
But you won't be able to put it back  if the FK Constraint is not respected, cause the `CASCADE REMOVE` won't happen (risk of orphans)

Or use `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE`.
Which will preserve the `DELETE CASCADE` behaviour.

**EDIT**

```
DELETE FROM dbo.masterTbl;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.masterTbl', RESEED, 0) -- will set IDENTITY count back to 0
```

Comment: I am using IDENTITY(1,1) and when i will insert new row after delete command then my next row id will generate with previous series..but i do not want... 

I do not want to remove Foreign Key Fk_mid...any solution???

Comment: Great sir it is working....
Please make correct it as 
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.masterTbl', RESEED, 0) 
instead of
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.masterTbl', RESEED, 1)